# Sudden swedish keyboard problem

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout, cinnamon, locale

I have a problem with my keyboard layout in any terminal.

Swedish keys/characters are suddenly not working anymore in any terminal.
Works fine in any gui application but not in any terminal.
But all other locale settings are still good,

Have googled and tried every suggestion I have found. Even restarted multiple times. Every other key entry are correct in my locale.
The key Ö gives me (arg: 6)
Ubuntu 18.10 with Cinnamon. Problem remains when switching to console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the command `locale` output when run in terminal?

Comment: `LANG=C  
LANGUAGE=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_CTYPE="C"  
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_COLLATE="C"  
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_MESSAGES="C"  
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8  
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Comment: `LANG=C` is the culprit. It disables UTF-8 encoding. Did you possibly set that in `~/.bashrc`? Whereever you set it, drop it.

Comment: Great, thanks. It works very well. Did try a lot of changes with those but not that. Added that to solve problems with navigation keys when using edit mode in vim.